# on closing dialog do not remove the previous contents on re-opening again

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have made a dialog and a UI Tab in that dialog. In that dialog i am showing some contents as a table. When i close the dialog by remove() method it closes the dialog but when i reopen it, the old contents are still showing with the new contents in the tab, is there any method that old contents will also reomve when dialog closes. I have used empty() but it seems useless below is my code.

```
this.formOrderList = null;
this.orderListDialogObject = $('<div id="mainDiv"></div>');
this.orderListTable = $('<div>'
        + '<table id="orderListTable" class="ui-widget tblBorder" width="100%" border="0"  cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">'
        + '<thead class="ui-widget-header" id="orderListHead">' + '<tr>'
        + '<th><strong> Order# </strong></th>'
        + '<th><strong> Symbol </strong></th>'
        //+ '<th><strong> Exchange </strong></th>'
        //+ '<th><strong> Market </strong></th>'
        + '<th><strong> Time </strong></th>'            
        + '<th><strong> Order Type </strong></th>'
        + '<th><strong> Side </strong></th>'
        + '<th><strong> Volume </strong></th>'
        + '<th><strong> Price </strong></th>'
        + '<th><strong> Trigger Price </strong></th>'
        + '<th><strong> Filled Volume </strong></th>'
        + '<th><strong> Status </strong></th>'
        + '<th><strong> Expiry Date </strong></th>'
        + '<th><strong> Ref # </strong></th>'
        + '<th><strong> Action </strong></th>' + '</tr>' + '</thead>'
        + '<tbody id="orderListBody">' + '</tbody>' + '</table>' + '</div>');
this.orderListTabs = $('<div>' + '<ul>'
        + '<li><a href="#pendingOrderList">Pending</a></li>' + '</ul>'
        + '<div id="pendingOrderList">' + '</div>' + '</div>');
this.orderListDialogObject.appendTo("body");
this.show = function() {
    $("#orderListBody", this.orderListTable).empty();
    this.orderListDialogObject.dialog({
        title : 'Order List',
        width : 850,
        height : 150,           
        close : function(ev, ui) {
            $(this).remove();
            return false;
            /*$(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
            return false;*/
        }
    });
    this.orderListTabs.tabs();
    this.orderListTabs.appendTo(this.orderListDialogObject);        
    $("#pendingOrderList", this.orderListTabs).append(this.orderListTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand fully, but if you need to remove the table, well you might just remove it

```
//Save a reference of the dialog
var myDialog  =  this.orderListDialogObject.dialog({
    title : 'Order List',
    width : 850,
    height : 150,           
    close : function(ev, ui) {
         //remove the table
         $('table#orderListTable').remove();
         //close the dialog destroing it
         myDialog.dialog("close");
    }
});
```

Comment: well the issue is when i am displaying a table in a dialog. when i reopen after closing the dialog the old conents are still showing up. for e.g tableA has value "1 2 3" next time when i re-open it, it is showing like this "1 2 3 1 2 3" instead it has to show like this again. "1 2 3"

Comment: I have tried ur code, when i reopen it again, the table is not showing up.

Comment: @Java_NewBie can you provide an example on jsFiddle.net?

Comment: Nicola its really hard rite now to put that on fiddle, but i can reffer u a post which i have posted 2 months ago on this same issue, and it worked at that time. here is the link of my posted question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136283/remove-a-dialog-is-not-removing-its-inner-contents

Comment: @Java_NewBie Have you tried using `"close"` instead of `"destroy"` ?